# Talend tmap nullable field usage

Tags: etl, nullable, talend

Could you please explain the significance of nullable check box in various places?

1. In tmap, under middle section with heading **Var**
2. In tmap under Input/output sections at the bottom panel
3. In any other component where we define the schema
4. Also, could you please explain the significance of KEY field while defining any schema.

Answer (score 2):

1. In tmap, under middle section with heading Var - it will accespt the null as value. if you are processing values which may result as null then check for nullable.
2. In tmap under Input/output sections at the bottom panel
   it has the same meaning column can accept or recieved null values.
3. In any other component where we define the schema
   very where it has the same meaning if you want to define a column with null acceptance then check this property other wise Talend will not accept null values and may raise the error.
4. Also, could you please explain the significance of KEY field while defining any schema.

Key filed denotes a Key column for database or any processing column, but most of time key property treated as KEY column(primary key..) for most of the databases.